# OpenGL and monochrome texture

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

Is it possible to pump monochrome (graphical data with 1 bit image depth) texture into OpenGL?

I'm currently using this:

```
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 1, game->width, game->height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, game->culture[game->phase] );
```

I'm pumping it with square array of 8 bit unsigned integers in GL_LUMINANCE mode (one 8 bit channel represents brightness of all 3 channels and full alpha), but it is IMO vastly ineffective, because the onlu values in the array are 0x00 and 0xFF.

Can I (and how) use simple one-bit per pixel array of booleans instead somehow? The excessive array size slows down any other operations on the array :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The smallest uncompressed texture-format for luminance images uses 8 bits per pixel.

However, 1 bit per pixel images can be compressed without loss to the S3TC or DXT format. This will still not be 1 bit per pixel but somewhere between 2 and 3 bits.

If you really need 1 bit per pixel you can do so with a little trick. Load 8 1 bit per pixel textures as one 8 bit Alpha-only texture (image 1 gets loaded into bit 1, image 2 into bit 2 and so on). Once you've done that you can "address" each of the sub-textures using the alpha-test feature and a bit of texture environment programming to turn alpha into a color.

This will of only work if you have 8 1 bit per pixel textures and tricky to get right though.

Comment: The 8 textures trick sounds interesting, but it is not really what I am looking for. I'm using the OpenGL to visualize data from my application, so such trick would slow down standard operation on the array (not speaking of programming complications).

Answer (score 14):

After some research, I was able to render the 1-bit per pixel image as a texture with the following code:

```
static GLubyte smiley[] = /* 16x16 smiley face */
{
    0x03, 0xc0, /*       ****       */
    0x0f, 0xf0, /*     ********     */
    0x1e, 0x78, /*    ****  ****    */
    0x39, 0x9c, /*   ***  **  ***   */
    0x77, 0xee, /*  *** ****** ***  */
    0x6f, 0xf6, /*  ** ******** **  */
    0xff, 0xff, /* **************** */
    0xff, 0xff, /* **************** */
    0xff, 0xff, /* **************** */
    0xff, 0xff, /* **************** */
    0x73, 0xce, /*  ***  ****  ***  */
    0x73, 0xce, /*  ***  ****  ***  */
    0x3f, 0xfc, /*   ************   */
    0x1f, 0xf8, /*    **********    */
    0x0f, 0xf0, /*     ********     */
    0x03, 0xc0  /*       ****       */
};

float index[] = {0.0, 1.0};

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,1);

glPixelMapfv(GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_R, 2, index);
glPixelMapfv(GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_G, 2, index);
glPixelMapfv(GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_B, 2, index);
glPixelMapfv(GL_PIXEL_MAP_I_TO_A, 2, index);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,16,16,0,GL_COLOR_INDEX,GL_BITMAP,smiley);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

and here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Have you compared its performance to the 1 byte per pixel variant?

Comment: It does not appear that you can clamp this texture without it changing shape. I was just trying to get rid of the cross border bleeding.

Comment: I found swapping the internal format to `LUMINANCE` produces the same visuals with a quarter the memory. If there are any formats smaller I would be interested. Idk how to get S3TC formats. I don't think pyOpenGL has those extensions.

Comment: this would look so much nicer with GL_NEAREST over GL_LINEAR :|

Comment: @Dmitry feel free to modify & add screenshot

Comment: the full source isn't listed; i'm struggling working with glTexImage2D with GL_BITMAP and GL_COLOR_INDEX and glPixelMapfv. I tried looking for examples and writing a proof of concept but nothing seemed to draw anything.

Comment: Is it supposed to work on forward compatible contexts?